# Seems in QuestDB the data is not available before commit log is committed data is not available in Realtime

Tags: questdb

Seems in QuestDB the data is not available right away.
like before the commit log is committed data is not available in Realtime to be selected.

is it correct?
can i make it also select from memory from the not committed data yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer,

https://questdb.io/docs/troubleshooting/faq#why-is-ilp-data-not-immediately-available

Well this is not what I expected, I hoped i could select from the uncommitted commit log too

is there an alternative?